# Do Hareidim wear a kittel on Yamim Nora'im?

Tags: clothing, chasidut-hasidism, high-holidays

I have never observed Hareidi minhagim during the High Holidays. But, I know that during Shabbat and Yom Tov many wear a *bekisheh* - a long robe.

I'm curious if they were the bekisheh in lieu of the kittel, or vice versa? Or, if they wear both, does the kittel get worn over or under the bekisheh?

Comment: I sense some confusion on your part or a simple misnomer: Not all “Hareidim” wear the “bekisheh”, only Hassidim (year-round on Shabbat and special occasions, e.g. national or personal holiday, while the Grand Rebbe or a *rebbishe einekel* [i.e. blue blood] will wear one daily).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to differentiate between Rosh Hashana, when a minority of people do not wear a Kittel and Yom Kipour where almost all the married men (not in their first year of marriage and not in Aveliuth) wear a Kittel.

On YK it's rare.

So, on Rosh Hashana, you will see long black jackets, bekishehs and other similar attire. I assume you're using *bekisheh* as a catch-all for fracks, long jackets, bekishehs, shtrockes and heavens knows what else they wear and call them.

Whether a kittel is worn over the *long jacket* or instead seems to be a personal preference. (Possibly based on your attitude to A/C and how well it works in your shul.)

Never seen anybody wear the kittel under their jackets, except at a Chuppa.

But, *Kittel* is a vague term in this context.

While many will exchange their long jackets for the classic kittel, others - Chassidim, usually, but not always - will opt for a white *long jacket* or white *bekisheh*.

Comment: “Rosh Hashana, when a minority of people do not wear a Kittel”; untrue.

Comment: @Oliver; from my 50+ years of observation on 4 continents and dozens of Yekkishe and Chariedi shuls and Yeshivoth, I can confidently say that most Charedim wear a Kittel on RH. Your mileage may vary... but what are you basing it on? (Obviously unmarried males do not count for this.)

Comment: My basis is also personal observation (albeit, not as pervasive) *and* corroborated by “the books”. Besides the fact that Rema only mentions wearing the kittel on YK (§610:4) and does not mention it in the laws of RH, see Nite Gavriel (RH [32:10](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46450&st=&pgnum=246&hilite=)) who says most communities don’t wear on RH, including Chabad (which you can also see at Otzar Minhage Chabad [p. 59 n.83](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30510&st=&pgnum=79&hilite=); although some differ regarding the *chazan*, rabbi, *tokea*)...

Comment: (cont.).... I’d add to the list a handful of very known Litvish yeshivos and, IIANM, yeshivos that follow the Gra too.